# Getting method help, while using Eclipse Pydev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I wonder, using `Eclipse's PyDev plugin`, how come documentation does not always show up?

[image]

Compared with

[image]

**Is there a way to set `Eclipse` to "always show modules available along with the help attached"?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that depending on each context, the PyDev type inference engine may know or not what you're talking about... In the first situation it knows you're dealing with a string and thus can show you things properly. In the second, word is probably some parameter, so, it can't really find swapcase properly -- although it should work if you did an assert isinstance(word, str).